# how to use single Modal dialog Component to show different data or message in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on application in Angular 2 and fairly new to it. I want to display Modal dialog on click of a Card. I have integrated angular material Modal popup in my app as instructed in [this](https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/making-use-of-dialogs-in-material-2-mddialog-7533d27df41) tutorial. Each of card have different Data and that data i want to display on same modal popup.
My Modal Component is :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
@Component({
  selector: 'confirm-dialog',
  template: `
        <p>{{ title }}</p>
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
        <button type="button" md-raised-button 
            (click)="dialogRef.close(true)">OK</button>
        <button type="button" md-button 
            (click)="dialogRef.close()">Cancel</button>
    `,
})
export class ModalComponent {
  public title: string;
  public message: string;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<ModalComponent>) {

  }

}
```

my Card component is :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalService } from '../services/modal.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
  private solutions: Array<Object>;
  public result: any;
  constructor(public dialogsService: ModalService) {

  }
  public openDialog() {
    this.dialogsService
      .confirm('Confirm Dialog', 'Are you sure you want to do this?')
      .subscribe(res => this.result = res);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and HTML is :

```
<div class="container self-card-container">
  <div class="row lab-work">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
      <div class="custom-card">
        <div class="card-header whatWeDo align-item-center">
          <div class="custom-header-image mat-card-avatar d-flex justify-content-center align-self-center" md-card-avatar="">
            <img src="./assets/what-we-do.png" class="align-self-center">
          </div>
          <div class="custom-header-text d-flex align-self-center">
            <div class="custom-card-title">What We Do</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-card-content">
          Co-Innovate with customers and partners in a "sandbox" environment to develop proof of concepts. Harness Emerging technologies
          to come up with newer solutions around existing problems. Provide an Immersive Experience to our customers of potential
          solutions for feel and function.
        </div>
        <div class="custom-card-action align-items-center">
          <button md-button class="read-more" (click)="openDialog()">Read More</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
      <div class="custom-card">
        <div class="card-header howWeDo align-item-center">
          <div class="custom-header-image mat-card-avatar d-flex justify-content-center align-self-center" md-card-avatar="">
            <img src="./assets/how-we-do.png" class="align-self-center">
          </div>
          <div class="custom-header-text d-flex align-self-center">
            <div class="custom-card-title">How We Do</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-card-content">
          We begin with problem identification followed by ideation phase to create an alternate point of view on the problem. This
          is followed by building a proof of concept or a prototype which is then handed over to customer for feedback. The
          whole process is repeated iteratively as desired.
        </div>
        <div class="custom-card-action align-items-center">
          <button md-button class="read-more" (click)="openDialog()">Read More</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
      <div class="custom-card">
        <div class="card-header howWeDone align-item-center">
          <div class="custom-header-image mat-card-avatar d-flex justify-content-center align-self-center" md-card-avatar="">
            <img src="./assets/how-things-get-done.png" class="align-self-center">
          </div>
          <div class="custom-header-text d-flex align-self-center">
            <div class="custom-card-title">How Things Get Done</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-card-content">
          We follow 'continuous flow' based development as opposed to traditional software development life-cycle to stay lean. An
          integrated application life cycle management gives us necessary agility and transparency.
        </div>
        <div class="custom-card-action align-items-center">
          <button md-button class="read-more" (click)="openDialog()">Read More</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Dialog Service is :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ModalComponent } from '../modal/modal.component';
import { MdDialogRef, MdDialog, MdDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ModalService {

  constructor(private dialog: MdDialog) { }
  public confirm(title: string, message: string): Observable<boolean> {

    let dialogRef: MdDialogRef<ModalComponent>;

    dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.title = title;
    dialogRef.componentInstance.message = message;

    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }
}
```

I want to display title and message of card on modal that is being clicked.

How to pass Data respective to card in Modal?

Comment: pls add code of `dialogsService`

Comment: @Dhyey added code for dialog service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the title and message as parameters to the openDialog() method, eg.

html:

```
<button md-button class="read-more" (click)="openDialog('My special title', 'My special message')">Read More</button>
```

component:

```
public openDialog(title: string, message: string) {
    this.dialogsService
      .confirm(title, message)
      .subscribe(res => this.result = res);
  }
```

EDIT based on question in comment:

The quick and easy way would be to add the message content as string properties of the component and pass these as the parameters, eg.

In component:

```
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
    private solutions: Array<Object>;
    public result: any;
    public dialogOneMessage = `<p>Stuff</p><p>More stuff<p><img src=:/photo.jpg" />
```

html:

```
<button md-button class="read-more" (click)="openDialog('My special title', dialogOneMessage)">Read More</button>
```

I don't really like this approach though - not a good separation of concerns having large amounts of html as component properties. If you have large amounts of complex data for each custom dialog you are probably better off creating a custom component for each of your dialogs and pass your custom component to the this.dialog.open() instead reusing the ConfirmDialog component.

Comment: Thanks .. however Title and message will be too large text and will have images as well..I wonder how should I handle this

Comment: I understand , with this approach We have to write public dialogOneMessage1,  public dialogOneMessage2,  public dialogOneMessage3 and so on....it make sense to have different modal component instead of reusing. Thanks !

Comment: how can we achieve if the content is a dynamic component...? could you please advise.