# Is it possible to fetch modal content from a div tag instead of Component in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a angular component named legend with html content like below.

legend.component.html

```
<div class="NotAModalContent">
   <label class="mat-option-text-label" (click)="openProficiencyLegendDialog()">Proficiency?</label>
</div>
<mat-dialog-content>
       Modal data content goes here
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
        Dialog actions goes here
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

And I'm opening this component as a dialog from another component named skills like below.

skills.Component.ts

```
openProficiencyLegendDialog(): void {
    this.dialog.open(LegendComponent, {
      width: '500px'
    });
  }
```

But here I don't want Non Modal Content of legend component to be part of dialog.

May be something like

```
openProficiencyLegendDialog(): void {
        this.dialog.open('Specify Div Tag instead of component', {
          width: '500px'
        });
      }
```

The idea is to make this modal component reusable. Where ever I want to use this model dialog i just need to use

Comment: I think it is not possible with `mat-dialog`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use single Modal dialog Component to show different data or message in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858339/how-to-use-single-modal-dialog-component-to-show-different-data-or-message-in-an)

Comment: @PankajPrakash That thread is more about passing parameters to a modal component. But Mine is a different one. I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want specific content from the component, you should use ng-template. Wrap the content you would like in the ng-template, and refer to the template instead of the component itself. I found a stackblitz which has a good example for that, using TemplateRef and without: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-mat-dialog?file=app%2Fapp.component.html